# Vue App Not Displaying reactor-link pieces

Tags: vue.js, axios, font-awesome, vue-cli, bulma

I'm trying to work through a tutorial that uses Vue and have gotten stuck. I'm not sure why my buttons are not showing appropriately. Where am I messing up? Thanks in advance for your help.

From the images:
Expected Outcome: Buttons at top right
Actual Result: Buttons at top right are missing

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <nav class="navbar is-dark">
      <div class="navbar-brand">
        <router-link to="/" class="navbar-item"><strong>Djackets</strong></router-link>

        <a class="navbar-burger" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false" data-target="navbar-menu">
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="navbar-menu" id="navbar-menu">
        <div class="navbar-end">
          <router-link to="/summer" class="navbar-item">Summer</router-link>
          <router-link to="/winter" class="navbar-item">Winter</router-link>

          <div class="navbar-item">
            <div class="buttons">
              <router-link to="/log-in" class="button is-light">Log In</router-link>
              
              <router-link to="/cart" class="button is-success">
                <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></span>
                <span>Cart</span>
              </router-link>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <section class="section">
      <router-view/>
    </section>

    <footer class="footer">
      <p class="has-text-centered">Copyright (c) 2021</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</template>



<style lang="scss">

@import '../node_modules/bulma';

</style>
```

index.html:

```
<body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
```

router/index.js:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'About',
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../views/About.vue')
  }
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

export default router
```

[Expected Vue: Missing icons on top right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYrl9.png)

[Actual Result: Missing icons on top right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQF2s.png)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the code is all correct, the issue has to do with sizing. The device display is small and activated the mobile version which is not configured yet.

Upon using a larger screen, or adjusting the zoom if you can not use a larger screen, the buttons appear as they should.